# Ajax method is not working in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using following JS code to call a web handler.
This code calls the handler perfectly JUST IN IE and not FF.

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
            url: "../MasterPages/AHMHandler.ashx?T=1",
            dataType: "HTML",
            success: function (msg) {
                document.getElementsByName('cartId')[0].value = msg;
                }
            ,
            error: function (e) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        Sleep(2000);
```

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: I don't see why it should not work in FF. Please provide more information.

Comment: Amit, Cant see any errors either in Fiddler or FireBug!
In IE it calls the handler successfully and goes through all serverside codes and returns back. 
But using FF it neither goes trough the handler nor the error function of Ajax call.
Any idea?

Comment: @amirmoradifard Can you check URL in Firefox

Comment: Using Masterpage/ahmhandler.ashx?T=1 works fine and triggers the breakpoints in my handler.

Comment: If you open up the console in Firebug you should be able to see any Ajax request pop up. If it's not there, it's not being executed - so the error may be before this function is called.

Comment: What's with the `Sleep()` call? That is almost certainly going to cause problems. (hint: `Sleep` doesn't work the way you think it does, especially when using Ajax or other async functionality).

Comment: Spork, I tried console and nothing appears there!
The strange thing is when I put an alert instead of Sleep(2000) function (To keep browser from redirecting after ajax call) the handler calls perfectly!!!

Comment: Yep, the sleep is your problem (and alert is also a problem... I'll write an answer to try to explain it in more detail)

Comment: Spudley, Sleep Function is my own function to keep browser from being redirect for like 2 secs.
function Sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Just for ref, a sleep function like that is a *really* terrible idea in Javascript. You should use a `setTimeout()` for that kind of thing. However, the point is still the same -- you have code that runs after the `$.ajax()`, and it will be blocking execution of your ajax success function. If you're doing a redirect right afterward, then the success function probably never gets a chance to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen the `Sleep()` call in your code, and your comment about `alert()`, I would say that your problem is with a lack of understanding of how Ajax code works.

When you mak an Ajax call, it is called **asynchronously**. This means that the call is made, and then the rest of your current function carries on running without stopping to wait for the ajax code to run.

The ajax `success` function will be called eventually, but only when the http request is complete. **In the meanwhile, your current function will carry on running**.

The point here is that you cannot rely on a given sequence of events if you have code in the same function that runs after the ajax call is made.

Putting a `Sleep()` there might make it appear to work because some browsers might see the sleeping time as an opportunity to run the ajax success function, so your code seems to run in the right order. Putting an `alert()` there will be even more likely to make it work, because the `alert()` will generally take more time before it is cleared, so the ajax function has more chance to run.

But you should not rely on either of them to get your execution sequence right.

What you should do instead is put the code that you want to run after the ajax call inside the `success` function. This is the only way to be sure that it will be run after the ajax call is finished.

Hope that helps.

**[EDIT]** Further clarification after OP's comment:

> Spudley, Sleep Function is my own function to keep browser from being redirect for like 2 secs. function Sleep(milliseconds) { var start = new Date().getTime(); for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) { if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) { break; } } }

Just for ref, a sleep function like that is a really terrible idea in Javascript. You should use a setTimeout() for that kind of thing.

However, the point is still the same -- you have code that runs after the `$.ajax()`, and it will be blocking execution of your ajax success function. If you're doing a redirect right afterward, then the success function probably never gets a chance to run.

An `alert()` would indeed make it work that because the `success` function will find a slot to run when the alert is cleared, before `Sleep` is called, but you shouldn't rely on that.

The answer remains the same: You should put the code that you want to run after the ajax call inside the `success` function.

Here's a your code with the changes made:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
        url: "../MasterPages/AHMHandler.ashx?T=1",
        dataType: "HTML",
        success: function (msg) {
            document.getElementsByName('cartId')[0].value = msg;
            setTimeout(function() { //this instead of your Sleep function
                 //this is where you need to do your redirect, or whatever else you're doing after the ajax completes.
            }, 2000);
        }
        ,
        error: function (e) {
            return false;
        }
});
//don't put **any** code here after the ajax call! put it in the success function.
```

Comment: Spudley, Thanks for the detailed response. 
I think your solution is good but My button has PostBackUrl and I need to POST a form to a payment gateway. Can I do this postback in Javascript it self instead of in my button?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. I know nothing about how your button works, as you haven't included any of that code in the question. But if it's the code that you currently have after `Sleep()` then you'd do it exactly the same as before; my answer just changes where you put it in your script. (if you need a more detailed answer than this, you might consider posting it as a separate question on SO, because it's would be going too far away from the original question)

Comment: Actually I have posted such a post couple of days ago but did not find any solutions. Here is the previous one:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064830/jquery-get-call-and-ajax-is-not-working-for-calling-ashx-handler